# Does “Riemann integrable $\Rightarrow$ discontinuity set is measure zero” need axiom of choice?

Tags: riemann-integration, axiom-of-choice

My intuition is that it requires the axiom of choice to prove that if a bounded function $f$ on a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Riemann integrable, the discontinuity set of $f$ is measure zero. Is this correct?

Comment: What is "null" in the context of ZF?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Are there variants of the usual definition? The definition I intend is the same as in ZFC.

Comment: It does look more involved than I had thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need the axiom of choice. You can read the standard proof [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability).

This proof involves the sets $X_{1/n}$, defined as the points whose [oscillation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillation_(mathematics)#Oscillation_of_a_function_at_a_point) is greater than $1/n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$. The set of discontinuities of $f$ is $\bigcup X_{1/n}$, since $f$ is continuous at a point iff the oscillation there is zero. For the shake of contradiction, if you suppose that the set of $f$'s discontinuities doesn't have measure zero, then there exists some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $X_{1/n_0}$ isn't a null set (otherwise, since any countable union of null sets is null, the set of discontinuities will have zero measure!).

Maybe you got confused with the choice of $X_{1/n_0}$, thinking that the axiom of choice was needed. But $X_{1/n_0}$ isn't chosen, it **must** exist if the set of discontinuities isn't null.

Comment: Don't you need the axiom of choice to prove that any countable union of null sets is null?

Comment: I don't think so, see here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Null_Sets_Closed_under_Countable_Union

Comment: I think that website proves the countable additivity of the Lebesgue outer measure from the proposition that the sum of countable sets is countable, where the axiom of (countable) choice is used.

Comment: This proposition isn't needed. See another proof here: https://www.math.drexel.edu/~tolya/Lebesgue%20null%20sets.pdf

Comment: Got refuted by myself! This last link uses that the countable union of countable sets is countable. I'll ask a question in MathExchange to clear this out.

Comment: Here is my question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592801/does-lebesgue-null-sets-is-closed-under-countable-union-need-the-axiom-of-choi