# Does "Lebesgue null sets is closed under countable union" need the axiom of choice?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, lebesgue-measure, axiom-of-choice

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4592431/does-riemann-integrable-rightarrow-discontinuity-set-is-measure-zero-need-a/4592469#4592469) question, it has been asked whether the fact that the countable union of Lebesgue null sets is null, uses the Axiom of Choice or not. My opinion is that it is not needed. Here's a proof of this fact taken from my class notes:

*Take a sequence $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ of Lebesgue null sets. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Define
$$A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n.$$
Since the sets $A_n$ are null, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a sequence of intervals $\{I_{nm}\}_m$ such that
$$A_n\subset \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty I_{nm}\quad\textit{and}\quad\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}|I_{nm}|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2^n}.$$
($|\cdot |$ means measure of the interval). Now, one could just say that the family of intervals $\{I_{nm}\}_{n,m}$ covers $A$ and has sum of measures less than $\varepsilon$, to get the desired result. But in this case one will be using the Axiom of Choice to prove that $\{I_{nm}\}_{n,m}$ is countable! So instead we proceed as follows:*

*Consider a bijective function $\varphi:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ such that if $\varphi(k)=(n_k,m_k)$ then $k\geq n_k$ (the function $\varphi(k)=(n_k,m_k)$, where $k=2^{n_k-1}(2m_k-1)$ does the job). Therefore,
$$\bigcup_{k=1}^nI_{\varphi(k)}\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^n\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}I_{km}.$$
It follows that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n|I_{\varphi(k)}|< \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\varepsilon}{2^k}=\varepsilon\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right).$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |I_{\varphi(k)}|<\varepsilon.$$
Finally, $\{I_{\varphi(k)}\}_k$ is a countable family of intervals and
$$A\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I_{\varphi(k)}.\qquad \blacksquare$$*

**Am I right in thinking that this proof doesn't rely on the Axiom of Choice?**

Comment: You are choosing, for every $A_n$, a sequence $\{I_{nm}\}$ of intervals witnessing that $A_n$ is null. But regardless of where this specific argument uses (some) choice, it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\Bbb R$ is a countable union of countable sets, while $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves both that countable sets are null and that $\Bbb R$ isn't.

Comment: Since you are assuming countable number intervals, does choice function/axiom of choice matter ? I think the problem might be before choosing the countable number of intervals. Can u clarify if i missed something ?

Comment: The question, as I asked in the comments to that question you link, is **what does Lebesgue measurable mean?**?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, if I understand you correctly, the definition I use of Lebesgue null set $A$ is that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a sequence of intervals covering $A$ whose sum of lengths is less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Balajisb, I don't choose a family of intervals. These intervals are guaranteed to exist since each $A_n$ is null (this is precisely my definition of null set).

Comment: @AndrésMartínez: That is **exactly** where the axiom of choice is used. Equivalently, you might say that given any family of non-empty sets, each one is guaranteed to have an element, so we can choose one from each set. What you really want is to be able to uniformly choose the intervals.

Comment: @AndrésMartínez Isnt your problem similar to proving rational numbers {(m/n) or (m,n)} is countable ? Are u implying that rational numbers are countable only if axiom of choice is true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is consistent with $\sf ZF$ that $\Bbb R$ is the countable union of countable sets.

It is not hard to prove, without any appeal to choice, that a countable set is null in the given definition. We can simply use intervals with rational endpoints, or even just intervals centred around each point in the set.

So, in models such as that, the countable union of null sets can be equal to the entire real line, which is certainly not null.

(On the other hand, if we require the the measure is $\sigma$-additive, then by definition the union of null sets is null. Incidentally, in the case above, every set of reals is null, which makes the measure kind of useless.)

Comment: Thanks! I really got confused because the proof I wrote is made longer for not reason at all!